# naming an unnamed index in existing Python Pandas 1.2.4 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’m trying to rename the unnamed index of a dataframe I’ve called “no_labels” using:

```
no_labels.rename(index={'Unnamed: 0':'new column name'}, inplace=True)
```

This produces no error, but does nothing, and the first column is in fact the (base) index, and remains unnamed. Am I doing something wrong? I did some reading and found that I could use:

```
no_labels.index.name = 'COUNTRY_CODE'
```

and found success. I am guessing this is because the index of the Pandas dataframe is a series? Thanks very much for any help or corrections!

screenshot of failed code:

[image]

Comment: try `no_labels.index.names = ['COUNTRY_CODE']`

Comment: Hello Anurag thank you for your comment - I did do exactly that, and it did work as you should be able to see above, but I don't know why...  Can you explain to me what I did wrong or misunderstood?  Thank you!

Comment: try `no_labels.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'new column name'}, inplace=True, errors="raise")`

Comment: @JeffCrosby you can't use `rename()` method for changing the name of axis

Comment: Thank you Anurag, appreciate your help very much!